# How to understand Turtlebot + Phantomx urdf build error message

Tags: urdf, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I too have a Phantomx Pincher Arm and Turtlebot(create), and am exploring cdrwolfe's phantomx package defined in http://answers.ros.org/question/102426/phantomx-pincher-moveit/. So that I can use urdf_to_graphix to get a visual urdf, I encountered a parsing error msg doing a check_urdf on the phantomx.urdf as well as the same error msg creating a new urdf with xacro.py.

```
"Error:   Failed to build tree: parent link [plate_top_link] of joint [arm_base_joint] not found.  This is not valid according to the URDF spec. Every link you refer to from a joint needs to be explicitly defined in the robot description. To fix this problem you can either remove this joint [arm_base_joint] from your urdf file, or add "<link name="plate_top_link" />" to your urdf file.
         at line 226 in /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-urdfdom-0.2.10-3precise-20140303-2236/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed."
```

The `<!-- joints -- >` part of the phantomx_macro.xacro file for the arm_base_joint lists a `<parent link="plate_top_link"` which does not appear anywhere else in the phantomx_macro..xacro.

```
</link>
      <!-- joints -->
      <joint name="${prefix}arm_base_joint" type="fixed">
         <origin xyz="${M_SCALE*14.5} ${M_SCALE*0.2} ${M_SCALE*0.2}" rpy="${M_PI*0} ${M_PI*0} ${-M_PI/2}" />
         <parent link="plate_top_link" />
         <child link="${prefix}arm_base_link"/>
         <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
      </joint>
```

What else must I include in my process to generate the visual complete arm urdf? I very much look forward to further exploring this very  comprehesive package and watching further development so that I can get my Pincher Arm up and running in Hydro with basic arbotix_gui then learning to use MoveIt!.
Ross

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168381/how-to-understand-turtlebot-+-phantomx-urdf-build-error-message/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure but if the proposed link doesn't exist elsewhere in your model, you can't use that as the error message suggests. Use another, existent link as a parent.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0